# Writing dates in csv files, some output as ######

Tags: java, excel, csv

I am writing an application where I let some threads write csv files with random numbers and random dates. However, some of the dates output as ######, but when I click them in Excell, they do show the correct date (e.g.11/4/2014 shows as ###### in Excell, but when I click on this cell, in the fx field it does show as 11/4/2014).

Here is how I write my dates:

```
    Random random = new Random();
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");


    writeLine(random, bufferedWriter, cal, df);

private void writeLine(Random random, BufferedWriter bufferedWriter, GregorianCalendar cal, DateFormat df) throws IOException {
        String randomDateString;
        bufferedWriter.write(Double.toString(random.nextDouble() * 100));
        bufferedWriter.write(",");
        randomDateString = createRandomDate(random, cal, df);
        bufferedWriter.write(randomDateString);
        bufferedWriter.newLine();
    }

 private String createRandomDate(Random random, GregorianCalendar cal, DateFormat df) {
        int randomDayOfTheYear;
        Date randomDate;
        String randomDateString;
        randomDayOfTheYear = random.nextInt(365) + 1;
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, randomDayOfTheYear);
        randomDate = cal.getTime();
        randomDateString = df.format(randomDate);
        return randomDateString;
    }
```

Comment: Expand the cell size.

Comment: That's because the excel cell is too small, I think. Try expanding it. When you open with a text editor you seeit fine?

Comment: it has nothing to do with the csv-output itself, it's an excel problem. try to either expand the cell as was stated already or/and change the cell date-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`######` is a piece of text that Excel uses to mark cells that are not wide enough to display the entire number within them. This only happens to numbers. You are writing your CSV file correctly. All you have to do is expand the column in Excel so it can display the whole date.